# How to make Java Canvas Game Loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, nullpointerexception

I've been trying to make a java game loop in canvas that runs render(Graphics g) and logic() but it isn't working.

I have already tried making a script that runs the two functions then calls itself again to create a loop.

Thanks in advance.

I tried this:

```
public class Canvas extends JPanel {
static GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
static int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
static int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
//Get the system time
long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
//Specify how many seconds there are in a minute as a double
//store as a double cause 60 sec in nanosec is big and store as final so it can't be changed
final double ticks = 60D;
//Set definition of how many ticks per 1000000000 ns or 1 sec
double ns = 1000000000 / ticks;    
double delta = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Zombie Run");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new Canvas());
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    loop();
}

public static void loop() {
    logic();
    render(g);
    loop();
}
public static void render(Graphics g) {
    System.out.println("Running Render");
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 500);

}
public static void logic() {
    System.out.println("Logic");

}
```

}

The error I got from eclipse is:

```
Logic
Running Render
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ZombieGame.Canvas.render(Canvas.java:41)
    at ZombieGame.Canvas.loop(Canvas.java:36)
    at ZombieGame.Canvas.main(Canvas.java:31)
```

Comment: You could use a [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). If that doesn't help, please post what you've tried in form of a [MCVE].

Comment: "a script that runs the two functions then calls itself again to create a loop" - a script should not be in java code. If its a method that calls itself you are on the way runnning into a stackoverflow. I wonder if you havn't  heard of the mighty `while` loop. If not than don't try to write computer games.

Comment: Yes i did try the while true loop but it threw an error and wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). A while-loop and `Thread.sleep` would just cause the GUI to freeze.

I made an example using the `Timer` class. It creates a timer with the delay of `42` milliseconds. Every time after that delay, it performs the code inside the `ActionListener`. The example paints random rectangles onto the panel, kind of like that one linux screen saver :P I don't think you have to worry about how I specifically did that too much, it's just to illustrate how a `Timer` can be used.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Foo().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel();

        Timer timer = new Timer(42, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.addNewRectangle();
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class GameRectangle extends Rectangle {
        private Color color;

        public GameRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
            setBounds(x, y, width, height);
            setColor(color);
        }

        public void draw(Graphics2D context) {
            context.setColor(getColor());
            context.fill(this);
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
    }

    private class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
        private final Random RANDOM = new Random();
        private ArrayList<GameRectangle> rectangles;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            setRectangles(new ArrayList<>());
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (GameRectangle rectangle : getRectangles()) {
                rectangle.draw(g2);
            }
            g2.dispose();
        }

        public void addNewRectangle() {
            getRectangles().add(createRandomRectangle());
        }

        private Color createRandomColor() {
            return new Color(RANDOM.nextInt(255), RANDOM.nextInt(255), RANDOM.nextInt(255));
        }

        private GameRectangle createRandomRectangle() {
            return new GameRectangle(RANDOM.nextInt(getWidth()), RANDOM.nextInt(getHeight()), RANDOM.nextInt(420),
                    RANDOM.nextInt(420), createRandomColor());
        }

        public ArrayList<GameRectangle> getRectangles() {
            return rectangles;
        }

        public void setRectangles(ArrayList<GameRectangle> rectangles) {
            this.rectangles = rectangles;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but could you alter it to just display one square because i don't really need multi colored square spam

Comment: @JacobGoddard Well, it's just an example I provided which demonstrates how a timer works. If you understand the basics of that, you can also achieve the thing you're trying to do with it. Just put your code of the `loop` method inside the `actionPerformed` method of a timer, without the recursive call, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.lang.Thread` and `java.lang.Runnable`.

Implement `Runnable` in your class and create a thread.
Remember to implement the run() method.

```
public class Canvas extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    Thread mainThread = new Thread(this); //Creates a new thread with Canvas runnable object.

    //code

    @Override
    public void run(){}
}
```

So, in the main method we start the thread.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //your frame creation and initialization code.

    mainThread.start(); //starts the thread.
}
```

So you've started the thread. Now the thread will enter in the run() method.

```
boolean isStarted = false;
public void run(){
    isStarted = true;
    while(isStarted){
        logic();
        render(g);
    } /* The thread will return in this loop each has finished a task */
      // It's useless to call this method because the thread does all.
      // Leave it to the thread.
}
```

Use threads because swing isn't thread-safe!!!!!!!!

NullPointerException is throwed because Graphics are not initialized.